# How to evaluate a condition in app.component from service in angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7

I have a problem with my app.component.html, i'm using this block:

```
<router-outlet *ngIf="!accessGranted"></router-outlet>
<div *ngIf="accessGranted" class="wrapper">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <app-left-menu></app-left-menu>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    <app-footer></app-footer>
    <app-right-menu></app-right-menu>
</div>
```

When the `accessGranted` is false i load the login theme, when `accessGranted` its true i load everything from the dashboard. Ok this is perfect, works i expected.
But the problem is... how to update the variable `accessGranted` from a service? currently i have this in app.component.ts:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ThemeService } from './services/theme.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  title = 'SmartliveWeb';

  accessGranted: boolean;

  constructor (private _themeService: ThemeService) {
    this.accessGranted = _themeService.accessGranted;
  }
}
```

**theme.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ThemeService {

  accessGranted = false;

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

When user login in the app i want to change `accessGranted` to true to change the theme, but always stay in false. Any way to apply the changes in app.component when the `accessGranted` in service changes?

Comment: ...this is not really the way you should build an angular application, I suppose to work through the tutorial on angular.io and maybe google for "angular login" to get a proper example... but do the tutorial first to understand the architecture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To update the value in the component you need to create an Observable of that variable, so when changes the variable fire the value and the component can listen it. For example:

```
  private static accessGranted = new Subject();
  accessGranted$ = ThemeService.accessGranted.asObservable();


onLogin(){
   if(loginSuccess){
      ThemeService.accessGranted.next(true);
   }else{
      ThemeService.accessGranted.next(false);
   }
}
```

And in the app.component you can subscribe as follow:

```
ngOnInit(){
   this._themeService.accessGranted$
          .subscribe((res) => this.accessGranted = res)
}
```

But I think this isn't the right way to do this. You can use as children route and use the route guards provided from angular like canActivate.
Have more information here: [CanActivate Doc](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, i use this example [Link](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/10/29/angular-7-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial) and everything works very good.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a method to service and make `accessGranted` an `Observable` or even better: a `BehaviorSubject`.

In service:

```
export class ThemeService {

  private accessGrantedSubject$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  accessGranted = () => this.accessGrantedSubject$.asObservable();

  constructor() {
  }

  setAccessGranted = (isGranted: boolean): void => {
   this.accessGrantedSubject$.next(isGranted);
  }
}
```

In component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  title = 'SmartliveWeb';

  accessGranted: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor (private _themeService: ThemeService) {
    this.accessGranted = this._themeService.accessGranted();
  }
}
```

And in template, you can use `async` pipe:

```
<div *ngIf="accessGranted | async" class="wrapper">
...
</div>
```

If you want to change the `accessGranted` property, you could call the `setAccessGranted()` method of the service.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

your assignment in constructor is wrong

```
constructor (private _themeService: ThemeService) {
   this.accessGranted = _themeService.accessGranted;
}
```

---

```
constructor (private themeService: ThemeService) {
   this.themeService = themeService;
}

login()
{
   this.themeService.login((res) => {
       this.themeService = res;
   });
}
```

in your theme service implement login and return `true` on success

Answer (score 1):

this can be achieved by using shared service. This is how the code will look like:

Create a new file Service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
    // Subject (emitter) for User Name Change
    AccessGrantChange: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

    // SetUserChange() - This method sets the local variable and emits the change
    SetAccessGrant(param: boolean) {
        this.AccessGrantChange.next(param);
    }
}
```

In your login component once you get the result from service, i.e in subscribe method write the following code:

```
this._sharedService.SetAccessGrant(newCityName);
```

Make sure that in the constructor you have injected the service class. And in app.component.ts file in ngOnInit subscribe to the event and change the value:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ThemeService } from './services/theme.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  title = 'SmartliveWeb';

  accessGranted: boolean;

  constructor (private _themeService: ThemeService) {
    _themeService.accessGranted = this.accessGranted;
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this._sharedService.AccessGrantChange
        .subscribe((value) => {
            this..accessGranted=value;
    });
}
```